# IEqualityComparer in c# not working?

Tags: c#

I have an IEqualityComparer in c#:

```
public class ScheduledTimeComparer : IEqualityComparer<ScheduledTime>
{
    public bool Equals(ScheduledTime x, ScheduledTime y)
    {
        if (x == y) return true;
        if (x == null) return false;
        return GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ScheduledTime schedule)
    {
        return schedule.Start.GetHashCode() ^ schedule.End.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class ScheduledTime
{
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int End { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following 2 list of ScheduledTimes objects:

```
List1 = [{ Start = 60, End = 120 }]

List2 = [{ Start = 180, End = 240 }, { Start = 60, End = 120 }]
```

Now when i use the above mentioned equality comparer like:

```
//Count should be greater than 0 because both List1 and List2 are not equal
var equal = List1.Except(List2, new ScheduledTimeComparer()).Count == 0;
```

The Count is always zero, What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Your Equals method will return true for {Start=1, End=2} and {Start=2, End=1} because it xors the two hash codes together. So the result will be the same whichever order you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List1.Except(List2...` looks for items that are in `List1` but not in `List2`. It sounds like you want to know if the lists are *equal* to each other. Here is one way to do that, using [`SetEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346516.aspx):

```
var set1 = new HashSet<ScheduledTime>(List1, new ScheduledTimeComparer());
bool equal = set1.SetEquals(List2);
```

Also, your `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations are broken. In `Equals`, instead of just comparing hash codes, you need to compare values to get accurate answers. And using XOR (`^`) in `GetHashCode` is weak, e.g. anything with `Start == End` will hash to 0 and both of your examples hash to the same value, `68`. [A better option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/781792) is to use multiplying by primes and addition to work out the hash codes. Also, since `int.GetHashCode()` returns the `int` itself, I omitted it. This will work better:

```
public class ScheduledTimeComparer : IEqualityComparer<ScheduledTime>
{
    public bool Equals(ScheduledTime x, ScheduledTime y)
    {
        if (x == y) return true;
        if (x == null) return false;
        return x.Start == y.Start && x.End == y.End;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ScheduledTime schedule)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return schedule.Start * 31 + schedule.End;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison works fine, the problem is that you're misusing `Except`

```
var equal = List1.Except(List2, new ScheduledTimeComparer()).Count == 0;
```

This is giving you items in list1 that aren't in list2. List 1 is a subset of list2 so you get nothing back. If you change it to;

```
var dif = List2.Except(List1, new ScheduledTimeComparer()).ToList();
dif.AddRange(List1.Except(List2, new ScheduleTimeComparer());
if (dif.Count() > 0)
    // the lists are different
```

Then you will get back 1 item and it will work as you expected.

Comment: If the "extra" item can be in either list, this will not work well: you'd have to have both of the above lines.

Comment: @TimS. I wouldn't go that far... The user didn't state exactly what he was looking for. If I want the symmetric difference then I would do `List<T> dif = list1.except(list2).ToList(); dif.AddRange(list2.Except(list1));` and that works perfectly well. Certainly not deserving of your down vote buddy, I explained his perceived bug which was really what the OP was looking for.

Comment: I didn't downvote, someone else did. I agree that the user wasn't explicit, so I just thought of that as a potential weakness in your answer, not a "this makes the answer useless" sort of thing.

Comment: @TimS. oh, yeah that is a fair point, I should have been less defensive. My answer would actually introduce another bug and since the OP didn't understand `Except` in the one instance my suggestion would probably just leave him thinking it's working without knowing any better...

Answer (score 1):

The count should be zero since `Except` is set difference and there is an element in `List2` equal to the single element in `List1`. The output sequence contains the elements of `List1` *not* in `List2`, and there are no such elements using your comparer.

Answer (score 0):

```
List1.Except(List2, new ScheduledTimeComparer())
```

means List1 \ List2 in group terms; that is, take all the elements in List1 not preset in List2. There are no such elements, so the returned result is empty.

Perhaps what you wanted to do is:

```
List2.Except(List1, new ScheduledTimeComparer())
```

Which would return a single result.